# CiviCase: Migrate historical logs

Tags: civicase

Since installing the new CiviCase extension (very nicely done, btw!), we see the following warning in our System Status:

> This database includes ~10 historical activity revisions based on the
> legacy format. This may not work correctly with some filters or
> reports. Consider migrating or archiving this data.

Anyone know what this means and how we can migrate/archive the data? I can't seem to find information on this topic.

Also, we set up this extension via git clone (which is what the instructions say), but that method doesn't seem to alert us when the extension is updated in the System Settings / Extensions page. Any way to get an extension notify on new releases? For now, I'm just re-pulling via git every so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At administer - civicase - civicase settings there's a setting for `Enable Embedded Activity Revisions`. The civicase extension suggests turning that off and instead using administer - system settings - misc - logging.

Migrating 10 log records probably isn't worth it, and the revisions setting hasn't worked properly in the UI for a few years now anyway so you probably don't have a complete set of revisions unless your case activities are mostly created by customizations/api, but if you want to test out the migrator there's one at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caseactivityrevisionmigrator

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. After switching to the new civiCase extension, I deleted all previous cases.. Still I see this notice about archiving the data.
I switced off Enable Embedded Activity Revisions and went to administer - system settings - misc -... but I do not see wich options I should activate? There is no "logging".
Any help would be great!

Comment: At Administer - System Settings - Misc you don't see an option called Logging? It should be the 3rd one.

Comment: Thanks @Demerit for the hint .. The French Translation was confusing. For the record it's called "Journalisation". This option is on, but I still see the anoying notice about archiving or migrating former data. Would it happen to be a "civicase trash" I should empty?

Comment: Ok I sorted it out using API explorer to "hard" delete cases in the databases :-)